# Что такое "взял накрыл", почему мне и без запятой хорошо?

Tags: пунктуация, лексическая-сочетаемость

> Он взял накрыл своей рукой её руку, углубился в меню и вынырнул
>   заметно расстроенным.

Comment: Это ж примерно то же самое, что "пойти купить выпить". )

Comment: Там - у тебя - инфинитивы, а тута - другое...

Comment: Причина отсутствия запятой разве не одна и та же?

Comment: Можа, хто придёт со справочником в зубах? Сумлеваюсь я...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это влияние очень часто встречающейся в речи конструкции "взял и сделал", которая, понятно, оформляется без запятой перед И. В ней используется частица "взять и". [Частицы взять, взял... + и, да](https://www.vestnik-mgou.ru/Articles/Doc/2917)

В данном примере И отсутствует, но *взял* остаётся частицей, пусть и усечённой (некоторые лингвисты считают это вспомогательным глаголом). ***Поэтому запятую всё равно не ставим.***

*Скорей взопреешь! И точно-взял бросил… Кому польза?* [Н. Н. Златовратский. Горе старого Кабана (1880)]

Может, проще добавить И, чтобы конструкция была полной?

1. ***Он взял и накрыл своей рукой её руку, потом углубился в меню и вынырнул заметно расстроенным.*** - Если *взял и* частица.
2. ***Он взял её ладонь, накрыл своей рукой, углубился в меню и вынырнул заметно расстроенным.*** - Если он таки *взял (глагол) её руку в свою*).

Answer (score 2):

Он **взял и накрыл** своей рукой её руку, углубился в меню и вынырнул заметно расстроенным.

В современном языке используются глагольные частицы ***взял и, взял да,*** они входят в простое глагольное сказуемое.

Вариант без союза И выглядит устаревшим.